# Converting the days from beginning of a year to a datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to convert a stack of numbers into `datetime` and I can't figure it out how.

For example I am trying to convert 335.57912037 - representing the number of days in year 2014 - into a `datetime`. The result should 01 December 2014 13:53:56.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) for that:

```
import datetime

day = datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1)
delta = datetime.timedelta(days=335.57912037)
result = day + delta
```

Please note, that there might be a rounding issue with floating point numbers and you can get results like `datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 2, 13, 53, 55, 999968)`.